# Pass encrypted values via AJAX returns incorrect values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, encryption

I' am using jQuery AJAX to pass variables for PHP file. When the encypted value goes through PHP its looks differenet from what I have in HTML DOM

**This is how it looks in HTML DOM**

```
<input type="hidden" name="meta" value="�!e�����">
```

The source code

```
$profile_id = 1;
    <input type="hidden" name="meta" id="meta" value="<?php echo encrypt($profile_id, ENCRYPTION_KEY); ?>">
```

**I' am generating the above encrypted values using this PHP function**

```
function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $encrypted_string;
}
```

**This is how it looks in JavaScript Alert (Same as above)**

```
�!e�����
```

**This is how it looks in PHP Encrypted version**

```
�!e�����
```

**This is the weird part when I decrpyt it, its look differnet**

```
N~\�7V��咮���a�2�YE�
```

It should have retured value of **1** after decryption

This is the PHP Side of it

**Decrypts the values**

```
$to = $_POST["meta"];
$to = decrypt($to, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
```

**This is the ENCRYPTION_KEY**

```
if(!defined('ENCRYPTION_KEY')){
    define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "!@#$%^&*");
}
```

This is the function for decrption

```
function decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key){
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
return $decrypted_string;
}
```

**This is jQuery side**

```
$("form#form-update-status").on('submit', function(){
    var form, url, wipit, status;
    if($.trim(wipit) == ""){
        form = $(this).serializeArray();
        url = "ajax/update-status.php";
        $.post(url, form, function(data){
            $(".button-update-status").html(data);
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you post how you're outputting the meta with the encrypted key?

Comment: @DaveChen I have edit the question. I' am making the POST meta into local **variable $to** `$to = $_POST["meta"];`

Comment: I mean, how are you generating `<input type="hidden" name="meta" value="�!e�����">`?

Comment: @DaveChen Please checkout the question again I have re edited under "I' am generating the above encrypted values using this PHP function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had probably something to do with character encoding during the post of the form. The easiest way to fix this is using base64 encoded strings to prevent special characters. Change your encrypt/decrypt to:

```
function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted_string);
}
function decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, base64_decode($encrypted_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $decrypted_string;
}
```

Furthermore read about escaping a bit on the internet ([official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)). You should really escape all your outputs. So change this statement:

```
<input type="hidden" name="meta" id="meta" value="<?php echo htmlentities(encrypt($profile_id, ENCRYPTION_KEY), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
```